# How to install, verify and update all Octave packages at once?

Tags: octave, package

Today I have installed Octave 3.8 with GUI on my Windows 7 machine. Is there a command that will install all the available Octave packages ? Then I would also like to see a list of all the installed packages, and update them at times. So is there a command that checks for updates of all the installed packages ? Thank you.

Comment: Can I ask where you downloaded the windows installer from? It's not on  http://sourceforge.net/projects/octave/files/Octave%20Windows%20binaries/ or http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Microsoft_Windows.

Comment: Sure, I had to do quite a search to find it. Installer exe file is here :
http://mxeoctave.osuv.de/octave-3.8.0-4-installer.exe

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. To answer your question `pkg list` will list all installed packages, not sure about updating them "en masse" though...

Comment: Did you read Octave's FAQ on [installing all packages](http://wiki.octave.org/FAQ#How_do_I_install_all_Octave_packages.3F)? It's just a plain really really bad idea with no equal in any other language.

Comment: I did read, but I don't understand it. Why a bad idea ? Ok, it takes more space, it may slow down startup, but what if I don't mind it ? 
Or some functions could come in conflict with others... If that's true, then that's an important thing they should take care of, not recommend to not installing packages. It's like I sell you a new cell phone, and recommend you to not send texts with it. 
And that also means, you could run into same trouble when using just 2 packages, if you are lucky enough to pick the right 2.

Comment: @JamesC it is not the same thing at all. Compare with other languages. Do you know of any where it makes sense to install **all** of their libraries? In Octave this is made even worse because it can't have namespaces for Matlab compatibility. Packages such as nan conflict with others by design. The aim of it is to change how Octave works. Anyone can make an Octave package. Octave is one program, and each package is a separate thing, developed by someone else. Octave Forge is just a handy place where many people place their packages to make it easier, but it is not all of the Octave packages.

Comment: OK. I can go with your explanation. I still think though, that some packages in Octave are more popular than others, and more verified. Like the ones you see on Forge. And downloading them all should be something ok and not risky to do, ... in my opinion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks as if `pkg update` will update all your installed packages. See the [documentation on `pkg`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/pkg.html) for more details.

I haven't found a way to install all packages, I am doing them one at a time using `pkg install -forge <package_name>`, which is a bit tedious. It is also giving me errors when trying to install `parallel`.

Comment: I experienced errors too. And not just with 1 package. Although it installed and seemingly it works, it threw errors after installing. Which doesn't make me feel too confident about using packages then.

Comment: There is no method in Octave to install or update all packages. The Octave developers recommend against it on their FAQ. That does not make any sense. Do you know of any language that allows such thing? Could you imagine anyone using Perl wanting to install of CPAN? Or someone of Python to install all of PyPi? Note that the packages in Octave Forge are not all of the packages. pkg was written to handle packages, not Octave Forge. Maybe this would be more obvious if it didn't had an option to download them automatically.

Comment: @carandraug Assuming you have all the necessary licenses, MATLAB allows you to install all the toolboxes and add-ons at the same time as installing the base MATLAB, in one go.

Comment: @am304 and that's one of Matlab behaviours I most hate. But anyway, you're comparing two different things. Octave Forge does not aim to be the Mathworks toolboxes. It aims to be that *plus* FileExchange. Would you really want to install all of FileExchange? Plus, some of Octave Forge package purposely change how *all* of Octave works, they can lead to very weird behaviour unless you really know what you're doing. That's why most packages no longer load by default.

Comment: @carandraug Fair point. I hadn't thought of it this way. It would be great though to be able to install the equivalent of MATLAB's toolboxes and add-ons automatically as part of the main Octave install. The user can then add the packages equivalent to the File Exchange as he/she desires.

Answer (score 3):

Load/Unload all packages at once by executing the following command

```
pkg load all
pkg unload all
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows/Mac there is an installer on http://octave.sourceforge.net/. This installs all(?) packages but you have to load them with "pkg load".